# Interpolate empty values in a data frame series using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a list of numbers which I have assigned as a data frame series as seen below.

```
 [0.0,
 4.98,
 10.68,
 17.12,
 23.56,
 23.56,
 23.56,
 23.56,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 50.82,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 117.84,
 159.9,
 159.9,
 171.79,
 171.79,
 171.79,
 190.28,
 190.28,
 204.07,
 210.31,
 215.97,
 222.58]
```

I wish to drop all duplicates and interpolate the missing `NaN` values based on the existing numbers in the list which are not duplicates.

After I `drop_duplicates`, this is what I got.

```
0
0.00 

1
4.98 

2
10.68 

3
17.12 

4
23.56 

8
50.82 

18
117.84 

25
159.90 

27
171.79 

30
190.28 

32
204.07 

33
210.31 

34
215.97 

35
222.58
```

I carried on with `df.interpolate(method='linear')` but I got back my original list of number, and the missing values were not interpolated. Any ideas that could help? Example of my Code is as follows:

```
 dlist = [...]
 df = pd.DataFrame(dlist)
 df.drop_duplicates()
 df.interpolate(method='linear')
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, you can try running the `dropna` function with `inplace=True`

Comment: ``df.interpolate`` fills NaN values with interpolated values. In your description above, I don't see any NaN values.

Comment: I see, how do i replace the duplicate values as NaN in that case? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
a = pd.Series(yourlist)
a[a.duplicated()]  = None
a = a.interpolate(method='linear')
```

Another solution:

Replace duplicated values to missing values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and and use [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
s = pd.Series(dlist)
s = s.mask(s.duplicated()).interpolate(method='linear')
```

---

```
print (s.head(10))
0     0.000
1     4.980
2    10.680
3    17.120
4    23.560
5    30.375
6    37.190
7    44.005
8    50.820
9    57.522
dtype: float64
```